# Why my node returns me a websocket error?

Tags: dataflow, total.js

I'm putting my application on an IIS HTTP server, but I get an error:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://xxxx.xxxx.xx:xxxxx/?designer=1&token=&baa=' failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

What could cause it?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur if 'PORT' is closed. To resolve this issue make sure that `PORT` is open.